# How to change the label content in a deform/colander form?

Tags: python, deform, colander

I have deform/colander generated html form, that contains this:

```
class ProductSchema(colander.Schema):
            completename = colander.SchemaNode(colander.String())
```

The generated form has therefore this label:

```
<label class="desc" title="" for="deformField1">Completename<span class="req" id="req-deformField1">*</span> 
</label>
```

I would like to override the label content to have something else displayed, like "Complete name" for example.

This is a probably very trivial question but I could not find the answer in the documentation
( http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/deform/dev/# )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To the `SchemaNode` you can provide a `title` argument.

```
colander.SchemaNode(colander.String(),
                    title='Complete name')
```